# How to clean a motor that has paint in it

Tags: paint, cleaning, electric-motor

The paint sprayer we are using got paint in the motor that blows the air out to spray the paint. Is it possible to clean the motor with paint thinner or motor cleaner? Or will paint thinner or motor cleaner ruin this electric motor?

**Some details on the sprayer**
[image]
This is where the sprayer head attaches. You can see all the way down to the back.

[image]
This attaches to the back of the part in the previous image. The motor is in this part and so any paint that goes through the previous part, comes right down into the motor.

It doesn't really make sense for sprayer not to have something to prevent paint down to the motor... But there isn't, so we wanting to see if we can clean the motor without ruining it...

Also, here is the motor...
[image]

Comment: Some pictures would help. Also, most if not all sprayers are designed to keep the paint separate to the motor as some paints give off volatile vapors and some motors produce sparks.

Comment: Lemme guess ... the filters got clogged up with paint, so you took them out - now the motor is clogged up with paint ... ?

Comment: Pictures of what specifically? Thanks for the info... this sprayer we have doesn't really have anything to prevent paint from going into the motor...

Comment: @brhans No, the only filters are for the air intake for the motor, and those are still currently in the sprayer. The paint came back through the airway and got in the motor.

Comment: Pictures of the on/in the motor would help.  Off hand would say leave the paint if the motor works.

Comment: I just added some pictures and a few more details... Also this sprayer is the Wagner Flexio 570

Comment: What kind of paint is it? If it's latex/water based, then paint thinner is the wrong stuff.

Comment: I don't think that you can clean the motor. Pretty sure you're missing parts or the unit was not assembled correctly before use. Paint shouldn't be getting into the motor like that. The paint should come up the supply tube and out the nozzle. Either the tube wasn't connected correctly or the seal is missing/defective. You could take this up with the manufacturer. From the instruction manual: __In the United States, to speak to a customer service representative, call our Technical Service at 1-800-328-8251. See www.wagnerspraytech.com in the “Contact Us” section for Technical Service hours.__